# Unable to run docker image: mountpoint for blkio not found

Tags: docker

I have inadvertently upgraded Docker from 1.7.1 to Docker 1.11. After this, since nothing worked anymore, I downgraded back to 1.7.1, but I'm not able to run my images any more.

Here is one of the command I'm using:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name tt_rss_database -p 20001:5432 -e DB_USER=tt_rss_user -e DB_PASS=PostgreSQL2013 -e DB_NAME=tt_rss -v /data/docker/volumes/postgresql/data/tt-rss:/var/lib/postgresql -v /data/docker/volumes/postgresql/run/tt-rss:/run/postgresql gentoo-pgsql-9.4
```

And here is the error I get everytime:

> Error response from daemon: Cannot start container
>   895f8a3a61c8e38e7dea5f5094031e8494d3060226efc856fa5d8234f321c9e7: [8]
>   System error: mountpoint for blkio not found

I didn't find any information on how to solve this issue.

What am I supposed to do ?

docker info:

```
Containers: 6
Images: 19
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:1-130958-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 2.452 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 37.47 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 2.834 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.145 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Data loop file: /data/docker/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /data/docker/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93 (2015-01-30)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.18.9-hardened
Operating System: Gentoo/Linux (containerized)
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.674 GiB
Name: mimir
ID: 623Z:WWF5:2UAF:QTJM:4PME:WNJM:FU53:ZBV2:AOEN:IWXT:CEA4:FVC3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the problems were once you upgraded, but certainly worth looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases) and your error logs to see if you can't use the latest version. Your best solution in the end is most likely going to be to recreate your images, so you might as well do that on a recent version and make further upgrades easier and potentially avoid security issues, etc. This is a pretty good write-up about upgrading to 1.9, while out of date is still a good reference: https://www.sourcelair.com/blog/articles/90/painless-docker-19-upgrade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do (Ubuntu paths here):

```
mount -t cgroup -o blkio blkio /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
```

and similarly:

```
mount -t cgroup -o devices devices /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
mount -t cgroup -o cpu cpu /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu
mount -t cgroup -o cpuset cpuset /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
```

This kind of situation can also happen after a

```
umount -a
```